select input value with jquery
how can I select the content of the word name within the value? In this example it would be hospitality.png
<input type="hidden" id="value_adjunto_certificado_vida_1" name="value_adjunto_certificado_vida_1" value=[{"isImg":true,"name":"hospitalidad.png","type":"image/png","size":100835,"url":"file.php?file=hospitalidad.png&table=curri_inscripcion&field=adjunto_certificado_vida&fkey=b2lvamlpt0fihux&hash=c41c2c0ac34198f0c2fa163355818079","thumbnail_url":"file.php?file=hospitalidad.png&table=curri_inscripcion&field=adjunto_certificado_vida&fkey=b2lvamlpt0fihux&hash=c41c2c0ac34198f0c2fa163355818079&thumbnail=1","isNew":true}]">


Please show us your attempts.

The value appears to be JSON. So you read the value, you decode the JSON - and then you pick the desired item out of the resulting data structure.

But first you need to make sure you've created valid HTML.

https://jsfiddle.net/ztqm9wxu/. adjusted quotes of JSON

You can use like this:
JSON.parse(document.getElementById("value_adjunto_certificado_vida_1").value)[0].name

But couple of problems though
Are you sure your input needs to hold a json value? You have kept it as hidden, so I am guessing you are just using it like a placeholder in some kind of form to store this value. Why not keep the value in different variable and toss it around as per requirement? Are you sure it will always be parsable? I am generally scared of storing RAW jsons as they can break my whole page. More so since I don't see your JSON escaping the special characters. E.g. I would have expected double quotes to be \" and not ".
